# working with django forms and templates

Tags: html, django, forms, python-2.7, templates

I am working with django frame work as fresher and my senior gave me the template and told me to create a Form which contains 4 fields(name,email address,phone number,message), the main task is the above field details when filled and clicked on send button the data should be received on his email address. Please help with this.

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <style>
      body{
        background: url('{% static "img/new4.jpg" %}') no-repeat center fixed;
        - webkit- background: cover;
        - moz - background: cover;
        - o - background: cover;
              background-size: cover;
      }

      </style>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Personality Leading.com</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/Custom' %}"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/Custom.css' %}">

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/clean-blog.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="mynav">
  <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white"><strong> PERSONALITY LEADING </strong></div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/home/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/about/">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/services/">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
```

Comment: Are this modal fields ..? You can call the ajax with 4 static fields and data send in your email

Comment: Where are you having problems? You need to write some Django code, we're not going to do your job for you.

Comment: Sir as this is a Bootstrap theme Html file I am not understanding how to create form for it.

Comment: @DeependraSingh yes sir they are modal fields but I don't know what is ajax.